# Why am I able to read a MySQL table with SELECT but I am sometimes unable to INSERT or UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL issue which troubles me for long time. Why sometimes a table is able to be `SELECT` but not able to be `UPDATE` or `INSERT`?

Maybe it is the reason of table lock. But I tried "SHOW OPEN TABLES", it doesn't shows table is locked.

Is there any other reason which will cause this problem?

Comment: Is the logged in DB user has INSERT or UPDATE privileges?

Comment: SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER will show you what your current user can do

Comment: If the "table" is a view, you might not be able to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why sometimes a table is able to be SELECT but not able to be UPDATE
>   or INSERT?

Most likely because the user you are connecting with does not have `UPDATE` or `INSERT` permissions.  You can check what `GRANTS` you have using a command like this in MySQL:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user_name'@'localhost';
```

Be sure to change `user_name` to the username you are using to connect to the server with.  Also be sure `localhost` matches the host you are connecting to.  But that said, MySQL `GRANTS` can be confusing. For example, I have seen some servers—when I had to clean up someone else’s work—where `localhost` would not work, but `127.0.0.1` would work so you might need to run the above command like this:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user_name'@'127.0.0.1';
```

And if you need to adjust your `GRANTS` then you could run this; be sure to change the `database_name`, `user_name`, `localhost` & `password` to match your setup:

```
GRANT USAGE ON `database_name`.* TO 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `database_name`.* TO 'user_name'@'localhost';
```

The first line `GRANT USAGE` grants basic usage to the database to the user.  The next line grants specific access rights and this is a fairly common stack that allows access to `SELECT`, `UPDATE` or `INSERT` items into the database as well as other sundry items.

That said, based on your comments it seems that this might be an issue where someone—or some code—with access to that database is running a [`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html%60) statement that would result in the behavior you describe.  Tables would be locked while work is done.  And then an `UNLOCK TABLES` would be run afterwards to allow `UPDATE` and `INSERT` commands to go through.

If you wish to debug & have server level access you might want to temporarily enable MySQL logging to see what queries are coming through. But remember: Activating the MySQL log is a resource hog & can slow down your server. Only do it during a window when you know you can safely test.

Using an Ubuntu 12.04 serve setup for an example, you would open op the MySQL config file like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then search for the settings for `general_log_file` and `general_log` which should be commented out & look like this:

```
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
```

Uncomment both `general_log_file` and `general_log` and then restart MySQL like this:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Now you can follow the MySQL logs like so with `tail`:

```
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

And if you see `LOCK TABLES` pop up in there, you know that is the cause.  To disable logging just comment out those lines & restart MySQL again.

Comment: Sometimes I can update it, means it takes less than 0.01 second to execute the update or insert query, but sometimes it can't, it will takes a very long time until timeout. So in this case, is it still permissions issue?

Comment: I have checked the permission, it shows "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES.... ", so I think there is no problem with the permissions.

Is it possible that something to do with foreign key?